# Keychain Error : How to store password in SYSTEM Keychain from MAC Application using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, vpn, keychain

I am trying to create VPN Connection from my MAC application and for that i need to store VPN Shared secret and VPN Password in SYSTEM Keychain.

I tried to use Keychain Class from [MACOSVPN Code](https://github.com/halo/macosvpn) but it's return an error with code -61 saying **You do not have write permission**.

Here is my code. Please correct me if i am going wrong somewhere.

```
// A generic method to create Keychain Items holding Network service passwords
+ (int) createItem:(NSString*)label withService:(NSString*)service account:(NSString*)account description:(NSString*)description andPassword:(NSString*)password {

// This variable will hold all sorts of operation status responses
  OSStatus status;

  // Converting the NSStrings to char* variables which we will need later
  const char *labelUTF8 = [label UTF8String];
  const char *serviceUTF8 = [service UTF8String];
  const char *accountUTF8 = [account UTF8String];
  const char *descriptionUTF8 = [description UTF8String];
  const char *passwordUTF8 = [password UTF8String];

  // This variable is soon to hold the System Keychain
  SecKeychainRef keychain = NULL;

  status = SecKeychainCopyDomainDefault(kSecPreferencesDomainSystem, &keychain);
  if (status == errSecSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Succeeded opening System Keychain");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Could not obtain System Keychain: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, NULL));
    return 60;
  }

  NSLog(@"Unlocking System Keychain");
  status = SecKeychainUnlock(keychain, 0, NULL, FALSE);
  if (status == errSecSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Succeeded unlocking System Keychain");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Could not unlock System Keychain: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, NULL));
    return 61;
  }

  // This variable is going to hold our new Keychain Item
  SecKeychainItemRef item = nil;

    SecAccessRef access = nil;
  status = SecAccessCreate(CFSTR("Some VPN Test"), (__bridge CFArrayRef)(self.trustedApps), &access);

  if(status == noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Created empty Keychain access object");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Could not unlock System Keychain: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, NULL));
    return 62;
  }

  // Putting together the configuration options
  SecKeychainAttribute attrs[] = {
{kSecLabelItemAttr, (int)strlen(labelUTF8), (char *)labelUTF8},
{kSecAccountItemAttr, (int)strlen(accountUTF8), (char *)accountUTF8},
{kSecServiceItemAttr, (int)strlen(serviceUTF8), (char *)serviceUTF8},
{kSecDescriptionItemAttr, (int)strlen(descriptionUTF8), (char *)descriptionUTF8},
  };

  SecKeychainAttributeList attributes = {sizeof(attrs) / sizeof(attrs[0]), attrs};


  status = SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent(kSecGenericPasswordItemClass, &attributes, (int)strlen(passwordUTF8), passwordUTF8, keychain, access, &item);

  if(status == noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully created Keychain Item");
  } else {
    //----------- ERROR ---------//
    // Here i got error with error code -61 Saying You do not have write access 
    //---------------------------//
    NSLog(@"Creating Keychain item failed: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, NULL));
    return 63;
  }
  return 0;
}

+ (NSArray*) trustedApps {
  NSMutableArray *apps = [NSMutableArray array];
  SecTrustedApplicationRef app;
  OSStatus err;

  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(trustedAppPaths) / sizeof(*trustedAppPaths)); i++) {
    err = SecTrustedApplicationCreateFromPath(trustedAppPaths[i], &app);
    if (err == errSecSuccess) {
      //NSLog(@"SecTrustedApplicationCreateFromPath succeeded: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(err, NULL));
    } else {
      NSLog(@"SecTrustedApplicationCreateFromPath failed: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(err, NULL));
    }

    [apps addObject:(__bridge id)app];
  }

  return apps;
}
```

Comment: "You do not have write permission" seems rather explicit… you need admin(/root) access to modify the system keychain.

Comment: I know this way :  "EditScheme"(From Menu by "Product->EditScheme...->Run->Info->Debug process as->root"). but if i want to do that without any root access then how can i do this? as i can't tell users to go and edit scheme and then run the application.
Can you guide me in this..?

Comment: @MalavSoni have you find the solution? Can you guid me, i am stuck because of this issue.

Comment: If you want to store password. You have to call the above code with from helper tool because we need to the admin privilege to store password in keychain and helper tool is running with admin privilege.

Comment: Is any chance to pass App Store approval process if we use helper tool which is running with admin privilege?